# Showing $ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^q \to E((X-EX)^q)$ in probability

Tags: probability, convergence

I am trying to show for $X_n$ iid st. $E|X|^q < \infty$ that

$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum^n (X_i - \bar{X})^q \to E((X-EX)^q)
$$
in probability.

I used the following approach: We note

- $ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \to EX$ in prob. by the WLLN, i.e., $\bar{X}_n \to EX$ in probability
- $ Y_i := (X_i - EX)^q $  are  iid

i.e. we use Slutsky on $\frac{1}{n} \sum^n (X_i - \bar{X})^q $ to obtain iid random variables to then use WLLN as per below:

$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^q \quad \xrightarrow{\text{Slutsky}} \quad \frac{1}{n} \sum^n (X_i - EX)^q \quad\xrightarrow{\text{WLLN}} \quad E(X-EX)^q \>.
$$

Now, I realised that, of course, once I applied Slutsky I have taken $ n \to \infty $ so I cant really take the last step via the WLLN. Can somebody help me fix this proof ?

Comment: (+1) Welcome to the site, PeeJay. If this is homework, please kindly add the `homework` tag. Like on math.SE, we give hints for homework and (usually) full solutions otherwise. If it's not homework, just say so. Thank you very much for showing your work and thought process so far! Cheers. :)

Comment: Here are some things to think about: (**1**) What does Slutsky's theorem say? In particular, think about if your first "convergence" statement appealing to Slutsky makes sense. (**2**) Is $q$ an integer? If not, then do you mean to have $|X_i - \bar X|^q$ and $|X - \mathbb E X|^q$ throughout? (**3**) What additional requirements on $q$ might you need? (**4**) Can you reduce it easily to a slightly simpler case which should, at the very least, dispense with some extra notation? When you've had a chance to think about this, you might consider making corresponding edits to the question.

Comment: (Also, if you're drawing the question from a particular reference, you might cite it.) Cheers. :)

Comment: **Please** [don't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) crosspost: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104003/convergence-in-probability-of-frac1n-sumn-x-i-barxq-to-ex-ex

Comment: Closed because a duplicate on maths mentioned by @cardianl got answered.

Comment: hey guys. does it make sense that questions should only ever be asked on one of the stackexchange forums (exclusively?). I m wondering whether potential answers might not have a different twist depending on which forum you are on ? (may be between maths and stats the difference won't be huge, but the point remains the same...)